# jQuery find the first attribut before an element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<tr data-commercial="commercial_8">
  <td class="tdCommercial">
    Mister X
  <h4>Planning</h4>
  <ul>
    <li data-day="Monday">
      <i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-1"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-minus-square fa-1"></i>
      Lundi
      <span class="number">2</span>
    </li>
    <li data-day="Tuesday">
    <li data-day="Wednesday">
    <li data-day="Thursday">
    <li data-day="Friday">
  </ul>
  </td>
<td class="Monday"></td>
<td class="Tuesday"></td>
<td class="Wednesday"></td>
<td class="Thursday"></td>
<td class="Friday"></td>
<td class="Saturday"></td>
<td class="Sunday"></td>
</tr>
```

With jQuery, I am using an `onClick` event with the element `<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-1"></i>`.

What is the best way to retrieve the `data-commercial` attribute on the first `tr` from this element ?

The structure can change, so I need something like "find the first data-commercial attribute before `myElement`"

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

> For each element in the set, get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

*Example:*

```
var commercial = $(this).closest('tr').data('commercial');
```

Note: Provided `this` refers to element `<i class="fa fa-plus-square fa-1"></i>`

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myElement').closest('tr').attr('data-commercial');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use closest:

```
$(this).closest('tr').data('commercial');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parents("tr").data("commercial")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.closest()` in jquery

```
$(this).closeset('tr').data('commercial');
```